# Как настроить форму обратной связи на сайте?

Tags: php, sendmail, mail.ru

Сайт на хостинге с cPanel. Почта используется с помощью biz.mail.ru. Помогите разобраться почему письма не отправляются.

Код в html:

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php">
<div class="field half first">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
</div>
<div class="field half">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your@mail.com" />
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="subject">Subject</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject..." />
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="message">Message</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
<ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special" /></li>
<li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

И файл sendmail.php

```
<?php
  $to = "test@mydomain.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  //$site = $_REQUEST['site'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  $headers = "test@mydomain.com";
  $body = "From: $name \n\n Email: $email \n\n Message: $message";
  $sent = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ;
  if($sent)
    {echo "<script language=javascript>window.location = 'http://mydomain.com/#contact';</script>";}
  else
    {echo "<script language=javascript>window.location = 'http://mydomain.com/';</script>";}
?>
```

Comment: Тут всё просто, у вас не правильно сконфигурирован `sendmail` http://php.net/manual/ru/mail.requirements.php. Нужно отправлять через внешний сервис. или конфигурировать.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать пример? Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Свой сервер настраивать тяжело и ни каких гарантий, что не заблокируют. Попробуйте https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer библиотека позволяет отсылать почту кучей способов. 
https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html - внешний сервис который позволяет 10000 емайлов бесплатно.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно на хостинге так защищаются от [уязвимости](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=45779) в PHPMailer.

Во `From` подставляй мыло, зарегистрированное на хостинге. А мыло отправителя в `Reply-to`.

Добавлено 22.01.2017.

Приблизительно так, не проверял.

```
$to = "test@mydomain.com";
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$headers[] = 'From: Darklez <info@darklez.com>'; //существующий email-адрес в домене на хостинге
$headers[] = 'Reply-to:'.$name.'<'$email.'>';

mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста чуть подробнее расписать?

Comment: Добавил. Стоит так же уточнить на хостинге.